# Creating dialog via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried the following on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YyySU/):

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>Hello.</p>
</div>

<a href="www.google.com">Link</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false }); 
    $(document.body).on('click',"a",function(event){ 
        if ($(this).hasClass('ui-dialog-titlebar-close')) return;
        event.preventDefault();        
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    });  
});
```

I want to achieve this same functionality, but by creating the dialog via JavaScript. That is, I don't want to have the `<div id="dialog" ...>` in the HTML. How can I do that?

Comment: You can have your HTML loaded via JavaScript `onLoad`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the dialog on click rather than just showing the dialog.  Here's an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YyySU/1/).

Basically you create the DOM node and apply the dialog directly through it. That's what can be done with the `$(HTML HERE).dialog()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own custom HTML statically and [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it to the `body` element or some other `div`, like in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/PT3xE/).

You'll have to position and style it yourself (either by giving it proper CSS classes or by using the `style` attribute). You can use your browser Developer Tools to take a peek at the jQuery-UI dialog `div` and "borrow" its CSS for position/style hints =) Although I highly recommend just using the jQuery UI dialog (as it handles the open/close aspects, has the option for a background modal, buttons, etc.). That's what the library is for! ;)

You can also dynamically retrieve the HTML in various ways, e.g. [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or many other methods.

Comment: I think your jsFiddle as the same code as mine. Perhaps you linked to the wrong one?

Comment: @MikaH. Oops, sorry! Although I highly suggest `claydiffrient`'s answer! It's much better because it uses the jQueryUI framework. Unless you wanted to do away with jQueryUI? Let me know and I can find the right jsFiddle, if not I think I may just delete my answer =)

Comment: I'm happy with jQueryUI. Yes, `claydiffrient`'s answer looks great. I'll vote your answer up anyway (Please correct the jsFiddle link). Thanks!